# Function prototype or not?

Tags: c, kernel

I found the following in the original linux kernel code. ([link](http://kernelhistory.sourcentral.org/linux-0.01/S/64.html#L5))

```
static inline _syscall0(int,fork)
static inline _syscall0(int,pause)
static inline _syscall0(int,setup)
static inline _syscall0(int,sync)
```

It can't be a function call since `static inline` is prefixed. It can't be a prototype since functions can't be overloaded in `C`. And there's no semicolon in the end. What is this?

Also, it is preceded by this comment (if you could explain this too)

```
/*
 * we need this inline - forking from kernel space will result
 * in NO COPY ON WRITE (!!!), until an execve is executed. This
 * is no problem, but for the stack. This is handled by not letting
 * main() use the stack at all after fork(). Thus, no function
 * calls - which means inline code for fork too, as otherwise we
 * would use the stack upon exit from 'fork()'.
 *
 * Actually only pause and fork are needed inline, so that there
 * won't be any messing with the stack from main(), but we define
 * some others too.
 */
```

Comment: Possibly a macro? Like, a macro that expands into something with a semicolon `;` at the end, prototypes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because `_syscall0` is a [macro](http://kernelhistory.sourcentral.org/linux-0.01/S/13.html#L128) (in `unistd.h`):

```
#define _syscall0(type,name) \
type name(void) \
{ \
type __res; \
__asm__ volatile ("int $0x80" \
        : "=a" (__res) \
        : "0" (__NR_##name)); \
if (__res >= 0) \
        return __res; \
errno = -__res; \
return -1; \
}
```

A simplified example:

```
#define call(type,name) \
    type name(void) \
    {return 0;}

static inline call(int,func)

int main(void)
{
    return func();
}
```

Expands to:

```
static inline int func(void) {return 0;}

int main(void)
{
    return func();
}
```

Comment: Cool. Thanks. Could you throw some light on the comment too? i know both are different questions

Comment: You are welcome, sorry I don't understand the quoted comment, maybe someone can enlight us

Answer (score 0):

What the comments are trying to explain is that, for normal implementation of fork() in the user space, copy-on-write technique is used. According to which the parent and child, both processes, share the parent's address space. The data in this case is set as read-only, as soon as any one of them tries to write into it a copy is made and they no longer share the resources.

In kernel space a single master kernel page table is present and it is shared among all the processes in the kernel space. If we try to create a copy of the master kernel page table weird errors may arise, as it is shared between many processes and many user level processes also refer to it at some point. Also it may be that the changes processes make to the master kernel page table be visible to other processes. May be that's why no copy on write is implemented here.

On encountering execve a new process is created and hence there are no changes done to the master kernel page table. It may be that while calling the system calls if functions are used then they may cause changes in the kernel stack, so to prevent that inline functions are used.